# GA4 data api - (not set) in custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4

We are currently using GA4 data API and faced the issue when custom dimensions returns value "(not set)".
We were using [the following article](https://help.analyticsedge.com/article/add-session-count-to-google-analytics-4-reports/) to set custom dimension for the session count, but we still receiving "(not set)" values.
Example of request:

```
{
"dateRanges": [
    {
        "startDate": "2021-09-01",
        "endDate": "2021-09-05"
    }
],
"offset": 0,
"limit": 100,
"dimensionFilter": {
    "filter": {
        "fieldName": "eventName",
        "stringFilter": {
            "matchType": 1,
            "value": "screen_view",
            "caseSensitive": true
        }
    }
},
"dimensions": [
    {
        "name": "customUser:applicationID"
    },
    {
        "name": "customEvent:ga_session_number"
    },
    {
        "name": "dateHour"
    },
    {
        "name": "platform"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionSource"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionMedium"
    },
    {
        "name": "sessionCampaignName"
    },
    {
        "name": "deviceCategory"
    }
],
"metrics": [
    {
        "name": "userEngagementDuration"
    }
]
}
```

Does anybody have any idea why it may happen?

Comment: The `customEvent:ga_session_number` will only be populated for days after the new Custom Dimension was registered. For example if you registered `ga_session_number` on 2021-09-10, `customEvent:ga_session_number` will not be available for 2021-09-05. What day did you register the custom dimension? If you request a report for today, is `customEvent:ga_session_number` available?

Comment: Hello, we have registered the dimension on 5th of August, but it is still appearing as `(not set)` while requesting the date of today.

Comment: Please open an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400. There must be something atypical about your GA4 property's configuration; this behavior and API request should work.